# Convert single rown to column heading

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table which I use the group by function to summarize different job types. I want the job type(field) to go across the top. what's an easy way to go about doing that?

```
OFFICE_CENTER   OFFICE_NAME        JOB_CATEGORY_1   TOTAL_HC
1               DEER PARK          Lead             10
1               DEER PARK          Lead1            6
6               ST THOMAS          Lead             4
5               HONOLULU, HI       Lead             40
5               HONOLULU, HI       Lead1            9
```

desired output

```
OFFICE_CENTER   OFFICE_NAME      Lead_Total    Lead1_Total
1               DEER PARK        10            6
6               ST THOMAS        4  
5               HONOLULU, HI     40            9
```

Thanks,
KW

Comment: You can use the `CASE` and `Group BY` to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test (office_center, office_name, job_category_1, total_hc) as
  2    (select 1, 'deer park', 'lead', 10    from dual union
  3     select 1, 'deer park', 'lead1', 6    from dual union
  4     select 6, 'st thomas', 'lead', 4     from dual union
  5     select 5, 'honolulu, hi', 'lead', 40 from dual union
  6     select 5, 'honolulu, hi', 'lead1', 9 from dual
  7    )
  8  select office_center, office_name,
  9    sum(decode(job_category_1, 'lead', total_hc)) lead_total,
 10    sum(decode(job_category_1, 'lead1', total_hc)) lead1_total
 11  from test
 12  group by office_center, office_name
 13  order by office_center;

OFFICE_CENTER OFFICE_NAME  LEAD_TOTAL LEAD1_TOTAL
------------- ------------ ---------- -----------
            1 deer park            10           6
            5 honolulu, hi         40           9
            6 st thomas             4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table. PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.

The following is annotated syntax for PIVOT.

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
[first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
[second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
...
[last pivoted column] AS <column name>
FROM
(<SELECT query that produces the data>)
AS <alias for the source query>
PIVOT
(
<aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sothing like this would help you:

```
SELECT OFFICE_CENTER, OFFICE_NAME, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Office WHERE JOB_CATEGORY_1 = Lead) AS Lead_Total, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Office WHERE JOB_CATEGORY_1 = Lead1) AS Lead1_Total

FROM Office 
GROUP BY OFFICE_CENTER
```